# HtmlHelper on ActionLink in Razor

Tags: razor, actionlink, tagbuilder

I use MVC3 Razor and have a link

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Obj", new { id = RSAuth.UserId })" class="gray-butt right">Edit</a>
```

I have written HtmlHelper

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyHelper(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, string href, string @class = null)
        {
            var builder = new TagBuilder("a");
            builder.MergeAttribute("href", href);
            builder.AddCssClass(@class);
            builder.InnerHtml = name;
            return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString());
        }
```

and this link is bad

```
@Html.MyHelper("Edit","@Url.Action('Edit', 'Obj', new { id = RSAuth.UserId })", "gray-butt right")
```

Comment: pls post the html produced or, if not available, the compiling error

Comment: there are no error, after render razor I get this <a class="gray-butt right" href="@Url.Action('Edit', 'Obj', new { id = RSAuth.UserId })">Edit</a> but I need <a class="gray-butt right" href="Edit/Odj/1">Edit</a>

Comment: @Emanuele may be it a simple question but I do not Know:)) Url.Action returns string but how this string put in my helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
@Html.MyHelper("Edit",Url.Action('Edit', 'Obj', new { id = RSAuth.UserId }), "gray-butt right")
```

remove the quote for Url.Action, because it is a function that return a string

Comment: I've not tested, maybe you should try @Url.Action instead of Url.Action i've proposed